# employee utilization in power pivot

Tags: excel, powerbi, pivot-table, dax, powerpivot

I've been strugling with this and searching for an answer for about a week so far..

I got a list of projects with a person responsible, utilization for each project, start and end date. Looks like that:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/2MpHOws.png]

What I would like to achieve is to get an utilization sum for every single date between project start (in fact min date) and project end (max date), like that:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/AfHRjEG.png]

In pivot table of course.

I tried to work with self-build dynamic calendar but I don't have a clue how to DAX it for every single date...

Please help!

Comment: Try creating a calendar table (see: https://radacad.com/creating-calendar-table-in-power-bi-using-dax-functions)

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a table with every single date and then bring that table into the data model.  Then use those dates as the column headers. Make sure your dates are in the same format as your table with information.  Are you using power pivot in Excel or PowerBI? The steps are similar but easier in PowerBI.